# Failing to Update Array in Firestore

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to update Array in Firestore. From what I know you cant just append to the array in Firestore instead you need to replace the complete array with a new one.

Following is the code in Kotlin where I was trying to update the array:

```
 holder.button.setOnClickListener {

         pending.add(o[0])
        Firebase.firestore.collection("profiles").document("YHMauLouORRtrYBV2h4dHJ5A0s72").update(

            "Pending" , "$pending"

        )
```

Here o[0] is the string I desire to Append to the already Existing Array named pending

Initialy in Firestore :-

[image]

Output I am getting :-

[image]

Output I desire:-

[image]

Basically While updating its converting the Array to a sting of list and pushing to Firestore. How can I get the Desired Output as shown in image ?

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's not how to update an array in Firestore. To achieve that, you should use:

```
Firebase.firestore.collection("profiles")
    .document("YHMauLouORRtrYBV2h4dHJ5A0s72")
    .update("Pending", FieldValue.arrayUnion("Banana"))
```

When you're calling update without the second argument it means that you want to update a regular field.